# Canvas Signed Request not being processed correctly

Tags: api, oauth2, oauth, authentication, canvas

I currently have a canvas app deployed across multiple orgs. This app uses signed request to authenticate a user. Along with some visualforce pages.

Just this morning the signed request suddenly stopped working across all our orgs.

Keep getting this error shown:

```
"Oops, there was an error rendering Force.com Canvas application"[MyAppName]
Your browsing session has ended or is invalid. Please re-login to Salesforce.com again.
```

Has anyone else had this error? It seems like something is wrong with salesforces OAuth2 infrastructure, as debugging in chrome console show this 401

```
PUT https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/services/data/v29.0/platformconnect/signedrequest?canvas=MyAppName 401 (Unauthorized) main.js:1522

POST https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/services/data/v29.0/platformconnect/traceevent 401 (Unauthorized)
```

We are raising a support ticket with Salesforce but would be good to know if anyone has any ideas about what is going on?

PS, tried across multiple browsers and logged in and out :P

Comment: Having the same problem, so you are not alone. It is working fine on the Chatter tab, but when I try running the canvas app in a visualforce page it brings up this error. Was fine yesterday night, so something must have been done on the platform.

Comment: Thanks, thats a relief :D I think it might be because of system changes because of salesforce1 being introduced. I'll update this post if we get any feedback from salesforce

Comment: If you preview the visual force page in the visual force editor it seems to work as well

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's back to working again, on the Salesforce1 mobile app, Chatter tab and Visualforce pages.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be back up for me yet

Comment: However it is working fine in Salesforce1, using Canvas with identical VF page code to the desktop web app, which is still broken in all orgs (Canvas embedded in Opportunity detail page). We're on eu2 instance, which one are you on?  And are you embedding Canvas in a longer page, rather than a dedicated VF page in its own tab (that still works for us)?

Comment: That was short lived, back to not working on VF pages and Salesforce1

Comment: Now OK - there was a Salesforce issue that is now fixed.